# Find the indices of 2 characters within a structure in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to find and return the indices if one of the NUM_PLUDATES are any of two characters

So far, I have done this, but I can found only one.

```
#define NUM_PLUDATES 4

int getDateTypeIndex(plutype *plu, char datetype)
{
    unsigned int dateCounter;
    for(dateCounter = 0; dateCounter < NUM_PLUDATES; dateCounter++)
    {
        if (plu->rec.DATE[dateCounter][0] == datetype)
        {
             return dateCounter;
        }
    }
    return -1; // none found
}
```

Then I have thought to do this:

```
int getDateTypesIndex(plutype *plu, char *datetypes)
{
    unsigned int i;
    int length = strlen(datetypes);
    for (i = 0;i < length;i++)
    {
        int idx = getDateTypeIndex(plu, datetypes[i]);
        if (idx != -1)
        {
            return idx;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

But returns only the first character. 
For example it returns only the 'C':

```
int index = getDateTypesIndex(plu, "CL");
```

Could someone please give me any help to get both characters.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what your expected behaviour is. Each function can only return one value. So what exactly do you mean "returns only the first character"? What else do you need it to return? Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the expected result and actual result.

Comment: @kaylum I want to find a way to return both characters in an array or structure somehow , but i do not the way

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
if (idx != -1)
{
    return idx;
}
```

You're returning on the first idx found.

You need to return some kind of array of the indexes found

Answer (score 0):

as in your code you write

```
 int idx = getDateTypeIndex(plu, datetypes[i]);
        if (idx != -1)
        {
            return idx;
        }
```

which will return the first index only (index zero) as return statement will cut the for loop and willn't continue once if condition is true